# How to modify HTML attributes inside a variable that contains HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable that contains some HTML elements & content:

```
var data = '<h1>This is a demo element. <span>This is a span.</span></h1><div id="div-element" data-id="1">This is a div.</div>';
```

What I'd like to do is modify the `data-id` within the `#div-element`.

**What I've tried so far:**

```
console.log($(data).find('#div-element').attr('data-id'));
```

This returns `undefinied`.

```
data = $.parseHTML(data);
console.log($(data).find('#div-element').attr('data-id'));
```

Tried to parse the HTML also, but it returns `undefinied` as well.

**What am I missing here?**

I'm using jQuery but a Javascript solution is just as good.

Comment: You should just generate data with the attributes you like rather than trying to parse it retroactively after initializing it.

Comment: With that html, you would have to use filter, not find

Comment: $(data) is giving you pure html. I am talking about the issue, you will understand it if you have lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `find()` yet there is no root element in the HTML string you're specifying; all the elements are siblings. In this case you can use `filter()`:

```js
var data = '<h1>This is a demo element. <span>This is a span.</span></h1><div id="div-element" data-id="1">This is a div.</div>';

var id = $(data).filter('#div-element').data('id');
console.log(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also note the use of `data('id')` over `attr('data-id')`.

Comment: Best answer, and an explanation that all other answers are lacking.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for the detailed answer! :-)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Is it also possible to modify the `data` attribute with the above? Or I'd need something else to do that?

Comment: No, you can modify too, `data('id', 'your new value here')`. Note that it won't appear in the DOM, but so long as you use `data()` to get and set the value it'll work fine. http://api.jquery.com/data

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think I'm misunderstanding something, because this doesn't seem to be working: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PQRaJb

Comment: That's because you're creating a new jQuery object each time. You need to create it once, store it, then perform all actions on that one instance: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PQRaQW

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ahh got it now! Didn't really think of that. Looks like I still have tons to learn in JS. Thanks a lot for your help man, I really appreciate it! :-)

Comment: No problem at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy element `div` and set `data` as its `innerHTML`

```js
var html = `<h1>This is a demo element. <span>This is a span.</span></h1><div id="div-element" data-id="1">This is a div.</div>`;

var div = document.createElement( "div" );
div.innerHTML = html; //set the html string

//change the attribute of the id-Element
div.querySelector( "[id='div-element']" ).setAttribute( "data-id", "2" );
console.log( div.innerHTML );
```

Comment: This is a additional overhead of creating actual DOM element inside document.

Comment: `$(data)` with jquery will do the same, which OP is already comfortable with. Also, it div doesn't get appended to the DOM anyways.

Comment: Why `div.querySelector( "[id='div-element']" )`?  Surely just `getElementById("div-element")` or `querySelector("#div-element")`

Comment: @Archer What is the problem with it? Are you aware that getElementById only works with document? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#Notes

Comment: Okay - ignore that bit.  What about using the Id, rather than looking for an id attribute?

Comment: @Archer What do you mean by *using the id*?

Comment: Why this - `querySelector( "[id='div-element']" )` and not this `querySelector("#div-element")`?

Comment: @Archer But what is the concern with it?

Comment: I'm not concerned - I'm asking why

Comment: @Archer I prefer it this way. Not sure why this answer is downvoted heavily. This is the only answer that does what OP asked for *How to modify HTML attributes inside a variable that contains HTML?*

Comment: Fair enough.  It's slower, obviously, when used on something larger so I'd call it bad practise.  And I didn't downvote so don't blame me - I was just asking why you'd do something so odd.

Answer (score -1):

In this case following will work.

```
$("<div>" + data + "</div>").find('#div-element').attr('data-id')
```

Comment: Hello down voter, Please mention reason for down vote. (If there is)

Comment: Some may call it bad practice, but I will not use `.filter()`(which is of course perform slower than `.find()` in case of large data)